# Pull Item Name using Netsuite saved search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, erp, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I want to extract Item name/number of a child item using saved search. Netsuite account contains item hierarchy Parent-> Child Item. Name of Parent is PARENT and Child item name/ number is CHILD. I have created a saved search for item ,While pulling the Child items name it is appearing as PARENT : CHILD. But I want it to appear as CHILD if Child item's data is being pulled. I also tried using {itemid} but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula to give just the child id:

```
case when instr({itemid},' : ')!=0 then substr({itemid},instr({itemid},' : ')+3) else {itemid} end
```

Answer (score 2):

Formula

```
LTRIM(regexp_substr({itemid},'[^:]*$'))
```

This returns only the Child Item Name/Number.